# Add a CrmLead opportunity on Partner creation

Tags: python, odoo-13

i just started studing Odoo 13 making some customizations.

I need to create a new Crm Opportunity when i create new contact.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, crmlead
from datetime import datetime

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'


    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        result = super(ResPartner, self).create(values)
        CrmLead.create({
            'company_id': 1,
            'priority': '0',
            'name': 'murri',
            'partner_id': 3705,
            'planned_revenue': 0,
            'date_deadline': datetime.date(2020, 10, 26)
        })
        return result
```

I tried to extend ResPartner but i give an error

**ImportError: cannot import name 'crmlead' from 'odoo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `destination` `model` which you creating from the `source` `model`.

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    CrmLead = self.env['crm.lead'] // Destination Object Environment Create
    result = super(ResPartner, self).create(values)
    CrmLead.create({
        'company_id': 1,
        'priority': '0',
        'name': 'murri',
        'partner_id': 3705,
        'planned_revenue': 0,
        'date_deadline': datetime.date(2020, 10, 26)
    })
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Odoo don't know what is meant by **`CrmLead`** for that you can do these things to get rid from this error.

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    CrmLead = self.env['crm.lead']    // Creating an object of 'crm.lead' model
    result = super(ResPartner, self).create(values)
    CrmLead.create({
        'company_id': 1,
        'priority': '0',
        'name': 'murri',
        'partner_id': 3705,
        'planned_revenue': 0,
        'date_deadline': datetime.date(2020, 10, 26)
    })
    return result
```

**Or**

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    result = super(ResPartner, self).create(values)
    self.env['crm.lead'].create({
        'company_id': 1,
        'priority': '0',
        'name': 'murri',
        'partner_id': 3705,
        'planned_revenue': 0,
        'date_deadline': datetime.date(2020, 10, 26)
    })
    return result
```